# Advice on suitable SRAM

Tags: memory, eeprom, sram

I'm kind of new to all this and the choices out there is kind of overwhelming when it comes to selecting a SRAM package and Flash eprom to go with a 10 Mhz Z80180.

I'm looking for a 128 KB SRAM and a small eprom to contain the boot code, the eprom needs to shadow the the first 512 bytes or so of the SRAM (for the boot up process).

Any advice for a good value alternatives is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the flash I would take parralel flash chip from some 2000-2005 years PC MBs, newer have serial flash usually. They are rated at 70ns, so should work at 10Mhz easily.

For the SRAM - not much production left of 'vanilla' SRAM, check out Samsung site, they still have 10ns 3.3 and 5v parts with various widths and sizes, price range - up to 10$ in retail). Most of these are in SOIC package.

For the 'shadow' functionality you would need some sort of memory controller (they were produced, but probably hard to find these days), but in your simple case you might wire chip select to OR of first bits of address bus, be sure to select fastest logic chips for this circuit.

Answer (score 0):

If you need 128 KB SRAM in PDIP-32 package, consider to use [HM628128ALP-x](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxuoE_w7cralVzBYQlJxZFI1d2M/) from Hitachi.

It's 128K x 8-bit SRAM, running in 5V. The "x" suffix is code for access time: 5=55ns, 7=70ns, 8=85ns, 10=100ns.